# How to simulate properly invoking a button via JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.10 in my project.

**HTML:**

```
<a id="btnStampa "class="btn btn-danger" href="" role="button" target="_blank" style="display:none;">
    Print
</a>
```

**JS:**

```
function Print(e) {
     var data = e.data.record;
     if (data.token==null)
         return;

    $("#btnStampa").attr("href", "Ristampa41/" + data.token);
    $('#btnStampa').trigger('click');

}
```

When I invoke Print method (within a table passing a token code) it doesn't open new window.
If set the button to visible, and I click after Print method invoked the working is that wanted

When I invoke Print method (within a grid passing a token code) it doesn't open new window.

If I set the Anchor tag to visible, and I click after Print method invoked the working is that wanted.

I also tried this code

```
$('#btnStampa').click();
```

but it doesn't work1

I need to have same behavoiur when I click on button but via JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try click?

```
$('#btnStampa').click();
```

**EDIT**

**Watchout:** in your HTML, **your ID has an extra space at the end** and this must come from it ;)

By the way, I'm no jQuery expert, but did you consider using vanillaJS?

```
var link = document.querySelector('#btnStampa');
link.href= "Ristampa41/" + data.token;
link.click();
```

This works like a charm.

Comment: if I put an alert onclick event on the Anchor tag the alert is raised but the new windows is not open!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e29n2duL/3/ it even works with jQuery with `click()` as i suggested, but jQuery returns you an array of elements, so you have to select one.

Comment: with vanilla is ok! Very weird! Why doesn't work with Jquery?

Comment: both of your are ok vanilla and sjahnan's solution.
you saved my life!

Comment: I'm the same person ;) glad it helped!

Comment: I' m a panic situation. Sorry for that. Thank you so much.